# Select UI Item, then Do something

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im working on a little marketplace system for my game. I'm trying to have selected item and then be able to purchase it. I've managed to figure out when item is selected, then if it is ~ I initiated a function which makes it able to purchase it. But, since I can only purchase certain item when it's selected, it deselects when I press "buy" button. This makes sense why it would, but how would I go around it?

Please look at my code to see what I've tried.

item script as far as selecting goes:

```
public void OnSelect(BaseEventData eventData){

        // do stuff when selected
        itemSelected = true;

    }

public void OnDeselect(BaseEventData eventData){

    // do stuff when deselected
    itemSelected = false;

}
```

onClick event for the button (marketplace script):

```
public void purchaseItem(){

    if (item [1].itemSelected) {

        // subtract price of the item from the balance
        pointsManager.gameCash -= item[1].itemPrice;

    }

    if (item [2].itemSelected) {

        // subtract price of the item from the balance
        pointsManager.gameCash -= item[2].itemPrice;

    }

    if (item [3].itemSelected) {

        // subtract price of the item from the balance
        pointsManager.gameCash -= item[3].itemPrice;

    }

    if (item [4].itemSelected) {

        // subtract price of the item from the balance
        pointsManager.gameCash -= item[4].itemPrice;

    }
```

All I'm trying to be able to do is to select a button (item) and then purchase it via onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here: By clicking on the Button Unity automatically fires a `OnDeselect` on all other UI elements. You can't really get around that.

---

I would rather implement it by myself using the [`IPointerClickHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) interface something like

```
public class YourSelectableClass : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public bool itemSelected;

    public void Deselect()
    {
        itemSelected = false;
    }

    public override void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // Deselect all others
        // Note that this only deselects currently active and enabled
       // ones. Later you might rather use a manager class and register them all
       // in order to also look for them only once
        foreach(var selectable in FindObjectsOfType<YourSelectableClass>())
        {
            selectable.Deselect();
        }

        itemSelected = true;
    }    
}
```

And than you could reduce the button method a bit using [`Linq FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) like

```
using System.Linq;

...

public void purchaseItem()
{
    var selectedItem = item.FirstOrDefault(i => i.itemSelected);

    // Nothing was selected => do nothing
    if(!selectedItem) return;

    // subtract price of the item from the balance
    pointsManager.gameCash -= selectedItem.itemPrice;

    ...
}
```

`i => i.itemSelected` is a lambda expression where `i` works as the iterator. It basically does the same as

```
foreach(var i in item)
{
    if(i.itemSelected) return i;
}

return null;
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*